# Как найти промежуток времени?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timestamp

Нашел скрипт который хорошо работает если брать промежуток времени например, c 13:00 до 18:00,но если я хочу взять промежуток, допустим с 22:00 по 02:00, то промежуток выводится не корректно, как можно решить эту проблему?
Суть скрипта: берет промежуток времени start_time и end_time в формате timestamp и разбивает на промежуток по 30 минут

```
function times(start_time, end_time) {
    var data = [
        [start_time, end_time]
    ], times = [], pair, i, n30, D = new Date(), H, M;
    for( pair=0; pair < data.length; pair++){
        n30 = (data[pair][1] - data[pair][0]) / 1800  ;
        for( i=0; i<=n30; i++){
            D.setTime( 1000 * (data[pair][0] + i*1800));
            H = D.getUTCHours() ;
            M = D.getUTCMinutes();
            times.push(
                ('<p>')
                +( H<10 ? '0'+H : H)
                +':'
                +( M<10 ? '0'+M : M)
                +('</p>')
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Время конвектирую с  2016-11-14 01:00:00 UTC в 946767600 (timestamp)

Comment: посмотрите в сторону moment.js

Comment: у вас там `setTime` используется. Оно вероятно оставляет часть **даты** неизменной а меняет только время. Поэтому переход в новые сутки дает не то что надо.

Comment: возьмите начальную дату-время, переведите в timestamp. далее в цикле прибавляйте по 1800 секунд, да выводите время получившееся.

Comment: @teran спасибо за комментарии, они помогли понять в чем была проблема

Answer (score 1):

Вообщем дописал, что если стартовое время больше конечного, то добавляем сутки к конечному:

```
if (start_time > end_time){
   end_time = end_time + 86400;
}
```